# Improving network latency - online gaming site

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, latency

I operate an online browser game that is very AJAX/database dependent, and the problem I am encountering is excessively high latency during peak hours.

I've created a simple AJAX ping that checks the server in a per-second loop, and the execution/response times of the 5 most recent pings are averaged into a "Connection Speed" that is displayed on the screen.

Most times, this latency records anywhere from 100-350ms, depending on internet speed, the client's other running webpages, and various other things.  However, during peak hours on my server, namely 10PM-11PM EST, this latency becomes so bad that my AJAX functions stop working.  The latency during these times can be around 2000ms, with some people seeing it as high as 6800ms.

My question is.. what would be the most likely cause of this?  Is it a hardware issue on my server?  Is it just unfeasible to create a browser game purely powered by AJAX?  During these times, I often encounter issues on the server itself, with my control panel returning many "Cannot allocate memory for selected task" errors, yet when I run `free` through SSH, not even 10% of the RAM is being used.

Comment: If that connection speed thingie runs on all clients I think it's contributing significantly to the server load...

Comment: How many requests are you getting per second? A simple webserver cannot scale infinitely. And most are not made to serve thousands of AJAX requests per second, but rather to serve more complicated pages.

Comment: some extra info needed: are you already running some kind of php accelerator?  And is the memory_limit in php.ini set to a reasonable value?  Your php process is running out of memory, not your host apparently.

Comment: Yes, the connection speed runs on all clients, all pages.  And during last night's test, there were around 2000 page views during the 10PM-11PM hour, so 2000/60 = 1 page request every 2 seconds?

Comment: @Derrick Tucker that simply cannot be true, you say you do an AJAX request every second for every client... yet you have 1 page request every 2 seconds?

Comment: @derrick that means that the ajax connection checker is not counted as a page view, because it runs every second.  Does responding to the ping request cause a lot of work for the server?

Comment: @Andreas I misunderstood your question.  Individual page views from clients average 1 every 2 seconds during the peak hour.  But every page view also pings the server once every second.  Average idle time on pages is around 4 mins, so unless I did the math wrong that would average around 130 requests per second?

Comment: @fvu No, the ping test itself doesn't run any code.  It simply loads a blank page, and a timestamp is taken before `.send()` and after `.readyState == 4`.  It's 100% AJAX powered.  I can't imagine that causing too much server load.  This ping test is not the only AJAX script running on each page.  The game itself is entirely AJAX powered, so there are usually multiple `setIntervals` running at the same time.. checking for updates to the game.  Is this bad practice?

Comment: @Derrick Tucker so you have about 260 active users at peak time? Anyway, I can't really estimate how much your webserver will scale, but `1000ms/130rs=7.5ms` per request doesn't seem entirely unlikely... meaning, your webserver simply can't handle the load. Even basic PHP pages will consume a few milliseconds, then add Apache and PHP overhead to that. Otherwise, perhaps slow SQL queries or too many SQL writes is the cause. Anything could be really.

Comment: @derrick as a first quick test you could reduce the number of pings to say 1 per 5 seconds, make sure it hits a static page (not one ending in .php, to make sure it's handled directly by apache and not piped through php), ensure you're already running an accelerator like eAccelerator, APC or whatever (especially in code-heavy environments a cache can speed up code execution by a factor of 10-100) and also have a look at your database to see if it's not dying under the load due to poor tuning like wrong or absent indexes.

Comment: @fvu Thank you for those starting points to go on.  Is there a simpler way to look at the database and see the load other than monitoring the process through SSH?

Comment: @derrick check this link for some tools that will help you monitor/analyze mysql: http://www.fromdual.ch/mysql-monitoring-solutions

Comment: Without checking your math, I'll just point out that an average of 130 requests per second is an average. You might well have some seconds that have no requests, and other seconds that have 5000. I think one of the SO admins recently published a blog article about this kind of problem (this kind of arithmetic). I can't find it right now, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are experiencing contention somewhere in your web app or database. This can be in so many places and therefore has so many possible resolutions that it is impossible to list them. Some of the things you can think about:

1. No threads available to handle incoming requests because they are making synchronous calls to the database which will lock the thread until the database returns thus increasing latency
2. Contention at the databse level. Are you using partitioning for your data to support true concurrency?
3. Are you serving static content through your web app which could be retrieved as a directly addressable resource?
4. Are you load balancing your web app?
5. Are you using caching on the web app?

It's a bit like "how long is a piece of string?"

Hope this helps some.

Comment: confused at that point 2: partitioning to achieve concurrency?  Even on say InnoDB tables where tables aren't routinely locked as is the case on MyISAM among others?  Valid points though, +1

Comment: Thanks for these things to consider.  I'll take them into consideration while I try to optimize the game.

Comment: @fvu - partitioning in the sense that you physically separate your data (say temporaly) onto different databases and use a resolver to point to the correct source. I am also aware of partioning in the sense of splitting your data files onto different physical disk partitions. This is also a good idea but not always easy depending on databse vendor.